# How can I style my php email reply in a table format?

Tags: php, forms, email, styling

I have a pretty basic php form processor which works fine. However, I would like the recipient to receive the email that isn't just flow on text with line breaks but prefer it is presented in table form so alignment is cleaner and legability of content is clearer.

My Code:

````
```
// Construct email body
        $body_message = 'Name: ' . $name . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Address: ' . $address . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Postal: ' . $postal . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Phone (day): ' . $day . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Phone (evening): ' . $evening . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Mobile: ' . $mobile . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Email: ' . $email . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Iwi/Hapu: ' . $iwi . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Current Position: ' . $job . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Current Employer: ' . $employer . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Qualifications/Experience: ' . $qualifications . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Skills: ' . $skills . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Contributions: ' . $contribution . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Referees: ' . $referees . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'Vision: ' . $vision . PHP_EOL;
        $body_message .= 'I have read and understand the policy: ' . $policy . PHP_EOL;
```
````

Any ideas please?

Comment: Please try html email format in php email header

Comment: you need to make a HTML email

Comment: But when I put it all in a table with tr and td tags I get errors.

Comment: Forgot the $headers content type. Now all good!